# How compliant are HTML5 websockets to accessibility standards?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, websocket, accessibility

One of the major requirements for accessibility standards such as WCAG is that the web site or application displays without the use of javascript or provides some sort of non JS alternative.  I did some initial research and couldn't find much information on this in regard to websockets.  Should I assume websockets are treated similar to AJAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Websockets require JavaScript to do anything useful, if you have a standard that requires you provide a non-JavaScript alternative, you will need to provide a non-JavaScript alternative that doesn't use Websockets. Yes, Websockets are just like AJAX; they're really just a way to create a persistent, 2-way connection rather than a one-time, request-response that AJAX provides. You should treat them just like you treat AJAX.

While WCAG 1.0 requires that you provide alternatives to JavaScript, WCAG 2.0 is more technology neutral; instead of requiring an alternative to JavaScript, it provides [a set of techniques](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/client-side-script.html) for making web pages involving client-side scripting more accessible. You should keep in mind that not all of your users will have JavaScript enabled; there are still some users who prefer to browse with it disabled entirely or by default. But accessibility technologies today are able to deal with certain uses of JavaScript, so you can write accessible sites even when there is no non-JavaScript fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer is good, but I figured I'd add some additional insights.

There's really two issues here: technology, and compliance.

As far as compliance goes, if for some reason you need WCAG 1.0, then you need a non-JS version. Because WCAG 1.0 says so. It used to be the case that some screenreader users would disable JS because it caused problems for screenreaders, but that's several generations of technology ago. A [recent survey of screenreader users on the web](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey4/#javascript) showed 98.6% with Javascript enabled.

As far as the technology goes, the issues with Javascript and accessibility really have nothing to do with Javascript itself: the accessibility issues have to do with the fact that something (usually Javascript) is *manipulating the UI via the DOM*. It's that manipulation of the UI that's at issue with accessibility; care must be taken to ensure that the resulting DOM is accessible, and that screenreaders handle the changes appropriately - eg using ARIA live regions to ensure that a screenreader will read out new content if that is appropriate, or that keyboard focus doesn't disappear and end up somewhere unexpected.

Any javascript that doesn't change the UI pretty much by definition will itself not have accessibility issues: so web sockets, web workers, local storage and so on do not in and of themselves have accessibility issues; what matters is if and when you update the DOM later on.